# I am installing wamp64 in windows10 but localhost not showing treeview

Tags: windows-10, wampserver

I am installing wamp64 in windows10 but my localhost ("cs01-pc/test") not showing or it's say as not able to show tree view in my machine or local host; How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Do you see the WAMPServer homepage when you run `http://localhost`??

Comment: Did you read the first dialog in the install process and install ALL the required MSVC C/C++ Runtime libraries? W10 does not come with all the old libraries annoyingly.

Comment: Did you install both the 32bit AND 64bit MSVC Runtime libraries as instructed in the first dialog of the WAMPServer install?